# How to count lessons or etc. after the preposition "after" (a habit in the past)

Tags: singular-vs-plural

If I used to enjoy talking with the teacher every time after her piano lesson, which would be true:

> I often enjoyed talking with the teacher after the lesson.

or

> I often enjoyed talking with the teacher after the lessons.

I took one lesson at a time.
But I enjoyed talking after the lesson many times in years.

Is the second one incorrect?

Comment: The second option - "...after the lessons" - is less idiomatic, I think. By the way, your introductory sentence says "...after her piano lesson." We think of it as _your_ lesson, not _hers_. So you could say, "I often enjoyed talking with the teacher after my lesson." That feels the most natural way to say it. (Though in the UK we talk _to_ people. In the US they talk _with_ people.)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Ah, I understand..! Thank you so much for very instructive information!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian -  There's nothing wrong or unusual about saying "talk *to* a person" in US English.

Comment: @stangdon: Sorry. I had the impression it had changed. Perhaps I only _notice_ when someone says "talk _with_." Thanks.

Comment: "talk to" is certainly common in the US, but is used more frequently to mean _informing/notifying_, (think _directional_ communication) vs. "talk with" meaning _undirected_, casual conversation. (Of course, context is everything.)